# Smooth animations with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, interpolation

Yesterday I started my journey into learning how to animate functions to do some small projects for my work. Right now, I'm trying to code a simple linear equation graph that only shows a dot at a time

```
from itertools import count
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

plt.style.use('seaborn-paper')

x_vals = []
y_vals = []
index = count()

def animate(i):
   x_vals = []
   y_vals = []
   x_vals*= 0
   y_vals*= 0
   var=next(index)
   x_vals.append(var*0.05 % 10)
   y_vals.append(var*0.05 % 10)
   plt.cla()
   plt.xlim(0,10)
   plt.ylim(0,10)
   plt.scatter(x_vals,y_vals)

ani = FuncAnimation(plt.gcf(), animate, interval=1)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Keep in mind that this is a super sketchy solution for what I'm trying to do.
My question is: is there a way to smooth my dot animation so it doesnt look choppy?

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to simplify your code which could help make it faster. Passing index as the function for the frames argument definitely increased the speed.

```
index = count()

def animate(i):
   var = next(index)
   v = var*0.05 % 10
   plt.cla()
   plt.xlim(0,10)
   plt.ylim(0,10)
   plt.scatter(v,v)

ani = FuncAnimation(plt.gcf(), animate, frames = index, interval = 1)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score -1):

If you look at [this post](https://towardsdatascience.com/animations-with-matplotlib-d96375c5442c) you will see (a) smooth animations, and (b) the author's use of optional arguments to `FuncAnimation`.